# Docker multi-stage build do not keep result of RUN command

Tags: docker, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm using docker-engine 17.05.0~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial to build this Dockerfile:

```
FROM wordpress:apache as codebase

FROM wordpress:cli as cli 
COPY --from=codebase /usr/src/wordpress /var/www/html

# Create a config 
RUN wp --path=/var/www/html config create --dbname=dbname --dbuser=dbuser --skip-check \
 && ls /var/www/html/wp-config.php

RUN ls /var/www/html/wp-config.php
```

But the output is not as expected. The code I copy from wordpress:apache is correctly added to /var/www/html, but the wp-config.php is only present during the actual build step, but not in the resulting image. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. When building, it ends like this:

```
$ docker build -t wptest . --no-cache
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/5 : FROM wordpress:apache as codebase
 ---> 1d3cc82944da
Step 2/5 : FROM wordpress:cli as cli
 ---> ee57985dea6f
Step 3/5 : COPY --from=codebase /usr/src/wordpress /var/www/html
 ---> e10d62f3d7bc
Removing intermediate container e09a35e05108
Step 4/5 : RUN wp --path=/var/www/html config create --dbname=dbname --dbuser=dbuser --skip-check  && ls /var/www/html/wp-config.php
 ---> Running in 8b2b3e98163e
Success: Generated 'wp-config.php' file.
/var/www/html/wp-config.php
 ---> b0934cfed497
Removing intermediate container 8b2b3e98163e
Step 5/5 : RUN ls /var/www/html/wp-config.php
 ---> Running in cda6a5c16fb5
ls: /var/www/html/wp-config.php: No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c ls /var/www/html/wp-config.php' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Why is the wp-config.php that's created in the first RUN not available in the next step, while the data I put there with the COPY command stays there?

(In case you're wondering what I'm trying to achieve, this is just a MCVE.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [wordpress:cli Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/b2f394ec850f4ac70e743a5017c634de719bdd42/php7.2/cli/Dockerfile#L43) declares `VOLUME /var/www/html`.  Once that `VOLUME` directive has run, [the content of that directory tree is fixed forever more](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes); your `COPY` and `RUN` statements that try to add things into that directory have no effect.

Comment: The copy has an effect. If I run the image, there are files in /var/www/html, it's just missing the wp-config. If I run the wordpress:cli image, /var/www/html is empty.

Comment: @TimStoop copy works because it operates directly on the image filesystem layers. The run command does not because it runs in a temporary container, and that temporary container gets an anonymous volume mounted over the image filesystem, where your changes go and get discarded.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! ... Should I mark this answer as the correct one? I can't mark a comment as such :/

Comment: @TimStoop David got you 90% there, give him the credit.